# непонятное поведение у чата

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь написать чат на Node.js с помощью socket.io. На своем компьютере (локально) все работает как мне нужно, но на уделенном сервере openshift , поведение у чата странное.

Вот код на сервере.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var username = 'аноним';

    if (socket.user) {
        username = socket.user.username;
    }

    socket.broadcast.emit('join', username, 'вошел в чат' );
    socket.emit('join', 'вы вошли в чат');


    socket.on('message', function (text) {
        var date = new Date();
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', username, text, date);
        socket.emit('message', username, text, date);           
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function () {          
        socket.broadcast.emit('userleft', username + 'вышел');
    });

});
```

когда я запускаю локально, то все работает корректно, то есть :

1. когда я закрываю чат, срабатывает событие disconnect и все
   знают , что я вышел.
2. когда я перезагружаю страничку с чатом, то срабатывает событие
   disconnect и сразу после него событие connection.

теперь, когда я заливаю этот код на удаленный хостинг, то поведение становится другое:

1. событие disconnect не срабатывает если закрыть чат.
2. оно (disconnect) срабатывает где-то через секунд через 70-80 , после открытия чата, независимо от того, закрывалась ли страничка или остается быть открытой.  Хотя даже после этого, я могу продолжать писать в чате(почему, как, фальшивый дисконнект?).

Почему такое происходит непонятное поведение?  Может быть есть некая настройка которую я не указал специально, и она зависит от хостинга?

Comment: А какую версию socket.io вы используете?

Comment: версия socket.io 1.3.7.

Comment: Добавьте в серверный код конструкцию `io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {console.log(socket.conn.transport.name);})` и сравните вывод на локальном сервере и на хостинге

Comment: Есть у меня предчувствие, что проблема в используемых транспортах

Comment: polling и локально, и на удаленном хостинге.
я на удаленном использую такой адресс для подключения
 var ip = 'ws://blablabla.rhcloud.com:8000';
а локально такой  var ip = 'localhost:*';

Comment: кстати, я не первый у кого эта проблема, вот еще человек без ответа остался (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020425/why-is-openshift-hosting-not-sending-over-the-socket-disconnect-function-is-the)  Кроме того, попробовал, практический "чистый" с сайта socket.io , и тот же результат, что наталкивает на мысль, что что-то не так хостингом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался, почему так странно вело себя событие disconnect.
В клиенте (в веб странице) был следующий код:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  var socket = io.connect();
```

Это работало, но только на локальном сервере, на удаленном хостинге же работало криво,
нужно было явным образом писать адрес на веб странице. Вот так:

```
var socket = io.connect('ws://адрес.rhcloud.com:8000');
```